# How do I perform a bitwise OR on .NET enums in script running with NLua?

Tags: c#, reflection, bit-manipulation, nlua

I have the following reflection code in C# which I'm trying to replicate using NLua script:

`G.Object.GetType().GetField("count", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);`

Everything is fine, until I try to use Bitwise OR operation on two flags. I have alerady tried:
`BindingFlags.Instance + BindingFlags.NonPublic` (arithmetic operation on non-number) 
`BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFLags.NonPublic` (not working, obviously, but worth a try)

I have also tried pure Lua implementations of bit-manipulation libraries. All fail, because what I'm trying to OR is called 'userdata' type in NLua.

Conversion of 'userdata' type using tonumber() also fails.

My current Lua code is below:
`obj = G.Object:GetType()
field = obj:GetField("count", *...two OR'd flags here...*)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to combine Enum flags with NLua is using the helper function `luanet.enum`

```
value = luanet.enum (BindingFlags, 'NonPublic,Instance')
```

Example: https://github.com/codefoco/NLuaBox/blob/00af36aa480281ae33835173430a806c54c2f9dc/Resources/source/OutputViewController.lua#L41